# Multiple emails with ZF2 & Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2

I'm sending emails using Zend Framework 2's SMTP transport, and through Amazon's Simple Email Service. Everything works great until I need to send more than one email in the same request - then I get this weird exception.

[image: Error Mesage]

`Fatal error: uncaught Exception 
   'Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException'
with message 
   'Could not read from email-stmp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
in 
   /www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php
on line 308`

I've tried doing an rset() on the connection, and it just produces the same error. Right now I've resorted to manually calling disconnect() after every send() - which makes ZF2 reconnect the next time and it works - but obviously not ideal.

I'm using ServiceLocator & Factories, therefore all this is happening on the one single connection (as it should).

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is the same email or different content? If same you can just put another addTo or addBcc inside same request.

Also try to check with amazon how many mails you can send at once, I know they have a limit on mail sending. (I used amazon for shared webhosting and I need to request permission to send more emails at once).